# XCode (4.3.2) auto-completion and IBAction

Tags: ios, xcode, autocomplete

I am trying to figure out the least annoying way to create IBAction in Xcode, without auto-complete slowing me down:

So here it goes, in the .h, I create an IBAction:
[image]

I type typing, autocompletion kicks in, awesome, let's press tab and tab the name of my IBAction
[image]

What's not showing here is the cursor, it blinks after 'myAction', but before the autocompleted '(id)sender'
So my first question:
1) how do you jump after 'sender' to add my ';'  A tab won't do it in this case.  I am using Command+right arrow, regular end of line shortcut, but feels like somehow autocomplete should be smart enough to respond to a tab, return, ...

Then in the .m I implement the method
I start typing -(IB...
[image]

Nice, let's do a tab and start typing the name of my method:
[image]

Ouch, we can see the problem coming here, I don't want multiple (id)sender...
And obviously, if I do one more tab:
[image]

which I end up having to clean manually

so that's for my second question:
2) How do you use autocompletion in this case, to avoid this problem

I have to assume I am doing something 'wrong', as I must not be the only one trying to autocomplete some IBAction...

Comment: This interaction drives me insane. I've given up on autocomplete for IBActions as I could never find a solution. I believe it to be a bug since all other methods with arguments don't behave this way.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do what you are describing. It is annoying. Command + right arrow is the best way I have found as well if you want to declare them in code first. An alternative, is to control-drag from your nib/storyboard and then declare the action like that. It connects to your interface and stubs out your methods all in one step.

Comment: If you create a control on the IB, you can just select it and hold control and drag to your .h file.  Then this creates the method signature (.h) and the implementation (.m) for you without even having to type it out.

Comment: I didn't know about the control dragging. I don't think I would use that as I still go faster with my current method (and I hate having the split screen on a laptop), but great tip anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer is your method. In my experience, I've only succeeded using command+right arrow. It doesn't bother me much so I don't think about it. Sometimes, I just keep my mouse at the right side of the screen so that I can easily click and have the cursor jump to the right most column... But that requires accuracy and I miss my row most of the times...

Comment: You can also use Control+E to move the cursor to the end of the line without moving your hands as far.

Answer (score 2):

I've suffered with this pain for way too long. Just found out you can type "- methodName" in your implementation and Xcode will autocomplete everything else for you.

[image: example]

Comment: Just to clarify this answer: if you declare your IBAction in the .h file, for instance `-(IBAction) doStuff:(id)sender`, which autocompletes just fine (in Xcode6.2); then in your .m file if you begin to type `-doStuff`, the method will autocomplete as: `-(void)doStuff:(id)sender`, with the cursor placed immediately after `sender`.  This is the best solution to the annoying "double sender" problem in my opinion.  Thanks joshbillions.